# How do I close a pdf file from the website so I can rename the containing directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf

using:
Windows 7
Asp.Net MVC3
Visual Studio 2010
All major browsers

My problem involves failing to rename a directory after opening a pdf file

1. I open a pdf from my website and it appears in a separate tab.
2. I close the tab by clicking on the little X.
3. I try to rename the file that contained the pdf
4. Get “Access to the path 'foo' is denied.”

Another manisfestaion of the same problem, probably.

1. I open and close the pdf from my website.
2. I then stop the website ( Blue square button in Visual studio)
3. I then try to manually rename the direcory that contains the pdf file that I just opened.
4. Get: "The action can't b completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program.
   Close the folder or file and try again."

If I close down Visual Studio completely, I can then rename the directory.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your folder permissions to see whether you/current user has access to change folder. You can right click on that folder and select Security tab. You may change the permissions for the user and try again.

2) How are you opening the PDF ? The mentioned error will come when there is some memory reference still with the file .  If open the file using window.open (path) and you close the browser instance which had the PDF, you should be able to rename the folder without any problem.

Comment: Sorry Shyju - I should have made it clear that I have no probelms renaming the file if I have not previously opened the pdf. I believe the pdf needs to closed somehow. I am afraid I do not understand you second question. I am opening the pdf with window.open(url path)

Comment: @user685555 : then u should be ok to rename the folder once you close the browser instance.check the file is opened in some other browser or adobe reader or something

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I need to to rename the file within the the website after I have opened a pdf file. Perhaps I did not make that clear either :-( I need to open the file AND THEN rename the folder BOTH within the website.

Comment: I guess, you may not be able to rename the parent folder when the child process is running. Its like fixing the engine while the car is moving.

Comment: Well thanks anyway Shyju. Hopefully someone who understands the problem will be able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a problem with Windows 7 hat has been around for a while but not yet fixed.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/in-windows-7-getting-error-the-action-cant-be/449b2e05-8ed0-4a72-98bd-dde430d27e10

I ran the website on a Windows Server 2003 machine and was able to rename the directory after opening a pdf file with no problems.